# Rails API login (no cookies)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are working on an iPhone app that's driven by API in rails. How would login functionality be implemented in Rails? We don't want to use cookies as it's not really 'web' so I am wondering how login is implemented in an API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Token Based Authentication`. Rails have `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` method which handles the authorization for token. Tokens help in authorization as they can be expired and recreated at any point. You can have a `:before_filter` to check for the authentication